# Paraview picture generation

Tags: python, paraview

I am trying to run a python script to generate pictures.
But every time i run i get the following error.

```
File "/usr2/tmp/Krishnamoorthi/case0383/New/Pics_0.py", line 16, in <module>
case_foam.SurfaceArrays = ['meshPhi', 'phi']

File "/cax/sw-cae1/OPENFOAM/LINUX_x86_64/ParaView/ParaView-4.4.0-Qt4-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.4/site-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 302, in __setattr__
"to add this attribute.")

AttributeError: Attribute SurfaceArrays does not exist. This class does not allow addition of new attributes to avoid mistakes due to typos. Use add_attribute() if you really want to add this attribute.
```

I checked the line 16 in the py script but it is all perfect.

Is it something to do with the bash for paraview??

Comment: Hello, could you give some details on the data you load with ParaView, and on the python script ? (for instance the whole script if not too long)

Comment: I would be surprised if it's a problem of the shell, it seems you are trying to access an attribute SurfaceArrays which is not there. What is in line 16? Wild guess, are you using something.CellData.SurfaceArrays instead of something.CellData['SurfaceArrays'] ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `SurfaceArrays` property does not exist on the `case_foam` reader instance.

Try opening the data data file in ParaView UI and see what properties are shown on the `Properties Panel`. There'd be some other property that should be used to select the `meshPhi` and `Phi` arrays to read for your reader.